# Possible to share ethernet connection over wifi without hosted network support?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I have this cute `Intel WiFi Link 4965AGN` wireless adapter which is obviously not supported by hosted network:

```
C:\>netsh wlan show drivers

Interface name: wireless2

    Driver                    : Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN
    Vendor                    : Intel Corporation
    Provider                  : Intel
    Date                      : 7/10/2010
    Version                   : 13.4.0.139
    INF file                  : C:\Windows\INF\oem285.inf
    Files                     : 3 total
                                C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\NETwLv32.sys
                                C:\Windows\system32\NETwLc32.dll
                                C:\Windows\system32\NETwLr32.dll
    Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
    Radio types supported     : 802.11a 802.11b 802.11g
    FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
    Hosted network supported  : No
```

It used to be working fine with ICS in Windows Vista *(IIRC)*.

So, I am thinking whether there are any hacks / software to make such kind of adapters work in Windows 7?

Or any ways to "rollback" the features (hosted network, ICS) such that they would work like what was in Windows XP and Windows Vista?